# Is it wise to ask salary raise for a company which probably would not do it?

Tags: salary, performance-reviews

Is it wise to ask a salary raise to your chief or just move on to another company? I am about to talk with her in a Personal Business Plan.

I like being here but my salary goes under-inflation and my company probably won't do a salary raise. If I say I want a salary raise, I just gave them the signal that I would be moving on, they might drop (they won't fire me but won't give me new projects maybe). I can't decide this because this is my first company, I came here back after my mandatory military service, I take a new offer from here with a good salary rise (good at that time) from when I came back from military service but now inflation hits hard overall.

They always say we would like to hear your problems and other things, I am only promising (for my perspective) and young person who can move on easily, they might accept it because I hold some projects that hard to transfer others (nobody in my department have these skillsets for these projects, I am the only Python'er guy and have some other domain knowledge).

It is really hard to decide, thanks in advance for the help.

Note: this is a big international company and salaries almost always average for all. I don't think they are looking for individuals performance.

Note 2: I work hard for like last 6 months, I improved myself a lot since then.

Note 3: Working here 1,5 years and having a break and then almost 2 years. Totally I have been working here like 3,5 years. I am probably getting underpaid.

Comment: It is something that you would talk with your supervisor about your progress and general evaluation about work. It should lead a proper pay rise as a result of a PBP but I think system currently does not work like that.

Comment: having more detail could help us. How long have you been in that company? are you underpaid, comparing to other folks in the same field? Location may also matter

Comment: @AlperAyna I don't know about the job market in your country/location, but this doesn't sound like a company you would want to stay or build your career further. If they never respond to requests for wage raises, that can only lead to you eventually being so underpaid that you are almost forced to leave..

Comment: @Blub You are right. I don't think they want me to leave, they just want me to work with these conditions and doesn't make any complaint about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Disclaimer: I don't know your country, culture/economics may make my answer not best suited to your case

### Asking for a raise is your right, and doesn't mean you will leave

It is normal to ask for a raise regularly. Of course, you can't ask a 10% raise each month, but an annual raise linked to inflation is, in my opinion, a minimum, as otherwise it means you lose money.

If you are doing your job well and if you feel you are underpaid, it's perfectly ok to talk about this with your manager and ask for a raise.

Asking for a raise doesn't mean you will leave, it just means you want to be paid properly according to your skills.

In fact, the real risk of you leaving is if you could be paid more elsewhere. Therefore, it's not you asking for a raise that will make you leave, but only them refusing the raise that will make you leave.

Edit:

3,5 years without a single raise seems a lot, even more if your country suffered from a high inflation during this time. If you think you could easily find another job, I advice you to just ask, and consider leaving if they refuse it.

Comment: In my country asking a rise probably means that I am unhappy about salary(obviously) and If the company won't make an improvement (it generally won't) this leads that I would probably leave. This gave a message to supervisors that I am unhappy and this makes them unhappy about me.

Answer (score 4):

No-one gets fired because they ask for a pay raise. Not many people get pay raises without asking.

Answer (score 2):

In your 2nd note you mention you've been working hard for the past 6 months.
Generally a pay raise would be requested/discussed yearly, unless otherwise stated during your contract discussion.

So while you should always be able to ask for a pay raise if you feel like you've been performing well or growing in your job, most companies are usually not too keen on granting a pay raise only 6 months after hiring someone.